# Mapbox iOS SDK setShowsUserLocation:FALSE causes crash

Tags: mapbox

I have an App with a specific tiled area. If the user is outside of this area and attempts to show their location on the map, I want the Application to reject the request and show an alert. The process I thought would be best is:

1. User taps button which sets `userTrackingMode` to `RMUserTrackingModeFollow` and sets `showsuserLocation` to TRUE.
2. In the map delegate, I respond to `mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:` and I check to make sure the user's location is within the mapView's tilesource bounding box.
3. If the user's location is outside the bounding box, I set `userTrackingMode` to `RMUserTrackingModeNone` and set `showsuserLocation` to FALSE.

When I set the `userTrackingMode` to `RMUserTrackingModeNone` nothing bad happens. But when I set `showsuserLocation` to FALSE I always get a crash similar to:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSSetM addObject:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x028291e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x025a88e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x028c8a7e -[__NSSetM addObject:] + 638
    3   IMAModularMapApp                    0x00243b02 -[RMMapView addAnnotation:] + 146
    4   IMAModularMapApp                    0x00247bdb -[RMMapView locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:] + 7115
    5   CoreLocation                        0x00c7355e CLLocationCoordinate2DGetDistanceFrom + 18294
    6   CoreLocation                        0x00c72af4 CLLocationCoordinate2DGetDistanceFrom + 15628
    7   CoreLocation                        0x00c6fe40 CLLocationCoordinate2DGetDistanceFrom + 4184
    ...etc`

Why is this crashing the App? Is there another place I should check whether the user's location is within the map?

Comment: The best way to discover is by setting an exception breakpoint.  Go to breakpoints tab on the left, bottom left is a plus sign.  You'll see the menu item there.

Comment: Yes I know how and where the crash is occurring (it's in the SDK code). My question is more specific about the SDK and where/how I should test for the user's location being within the tilesource's bounding box in due to the fact that it is crashing.

Comment: How about posting the SDK header declaration of showsuserLocation?  If you're setting it to FALSE (which == NO == 0), and it's expecting an object (like @0), then that's the exact crash you'd see if the SDK put that scalar value into an NSMutableSet.

Comment: @Danh ```showsuserLocation``` is a BOOLean property which has it's set method overrided to include a process to instigate the start user tracking within the App. Again, this is a matter of trying to find out what process I need to go through to prevent user tracking based on region using the SDK - not checking for bugs in the SDK specifically.

Comment: I think the best way I can help you is to suggest a rewrite on the question: title should be like: "How to exclude a region from tracking in Mabbox".  The body should be like: "Here's the *code I wrote* to do that, but it doesn't work.  In fact, it crashes on *this line in my source*.  Put the ios tag back in and replace the crash log with one line that says "the crash log shows a nil insertion into a set".

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend altering `mapView.userTrackingMode` if you aren't going to use the default behavior of the map always moving to actually track the user. Instead, I'd leave that as `RMUserTrackingModeNone`, implement your own `CLLocationManager`, and in the delegate callbacks on user location, check if they meet your conditions. If they do, I'd add your own `RMAnnotation` to the map for the user instead of relying on the default `RMUserLocation` annotation. You can borrow from its implementation (both in that class as well as within `RMMapView`) to make it look right.

Comment: OK, so there is no built-in ability to "approve" a user's location as being valid for the map? I guess that rules out user tracking for any tile sets that are not global without creating a custom GPS bubble. Otherwise it just moves to whitespace.

Comment: No, there isn't, but when you word it that way, it sounds like a pretty useful feature. I could see a callback in `RMMapViewDelegate` being added to support that sort of functionality. Want to open a ticket and/or a pull request?